# Compiz is taking more than 100% CPU

Tags: 13.04, compiz

My system was prompting for update and I updated softwares
Now system is very slow.
i checked and found that Compiz was taking more than 100% cpu .I think this is making system slow

Comment: @Dee Actually, a process *can report* using over 100% of the CPU. It may depend upon the tool by which you monitor processes. I have seen this using `top` quite often with numerous process. I haven't seen this while using `htop`. YMMV. No need to call the OPs info nonsense.

Comment: @maggotbrain Actually, you can see on 'top' milions of %, but this does not mean, that it really does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall compiz, due to the amount of information which you have given me to work with, I can not confidently asses your issue.